# Android Studio Build Variants

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm dealing with a project that has a large number of dependencies. This has become a problem because when adding new SDK's we're going past the maximum limit of methods that an APK can hold (65536).

I'm looking at using the new build system in Android Studio in order to create build variants that rely on subsets of our dependencies. I was able to find a number of tutorials that help with creating different class alternatives using build flavours, but I didn't find anything regarding specifying different dependencies for each flavour. Is this even possible? What would the whole workflow look like?

For example, I would like to create a build variant that removes Flurry support. I would be able to create a different class that does not instantiate the Flurry SDK, but I would also like to be able to remove the lib dependency entirely, in order to reduce the total number of methods in the APK.

I'm also open to any suggestion regarding managing this kind of issue :)

Comment: may be of interest: http://duckseason.mobi/how-to-setup-gradle-for-existing-libgdx-multi-project-using-the-google-android-plug-in-2/

Comment: In general, yes, you can -- in your dependencies statement, instead of `compile 'path.to.dependency'`, for example, you have `flavor1Compile 'path.to.dependency'`. Is that sufficient or do you need more information? If so, please expand on it in your question.

Comment: @ScottBarta: So basically I would create flavours that contain the classes that change from the main tree, and I would replace compile with flavourNameCompile, does it sound correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how you have flavor-specific dependencies, which was part of your question. As to whether or not your whole workflow/concept will work, I'm not sure. It will be pretty difficult to manage, but when you hit the 64k method limit, you don't really have any good choices.

Comment: What I would like to achieve ideally is something similar to what's happening in the iOS tree, where I can have "flavour" specific code wrapped between #IFDEFs so that I can easily "configure" a build based on a few constants. I'm trying to find a workflow that's as close to that as possible, so that's why I'm experimenting with this. Thank you for the flavour specific dependencies mention, I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: I'm not sure how this flavor1Compile statement works, AS says 'cannot resolve symbol'. Tried flavor1.Compile same results. Tried addingn dependency inside the productFlavors { flavor1 { compile ... AS says cannot resolve symbol 'compile'. If you solved this, can you actually write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This works (making sure dependencies are listed after productFlavors):

```
android {
...
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 { ...
    ...
dependencies {
    flavor1Compile ...
}
```

But this won't work:

```
android {
...
dependencies {
    flavor1Compile ...
}
...
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 { ...
    ...
```